# Stack.overflow vs. stack.exchange

Tags: support

The site "Stack overflow" is mentioned on my math.stackexchange page. 
What are the two sites' relations?

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow is part of StackExchange, which is the organisation running all these blah.stackexchange sites and some others.

Please see  https://stackexchange.com/ for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found the answer - in math.stackexchange -  after having written the question on google.

Comment: @MikaelJensen If your question receives a satisfactory answer on any SE site, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of answer. (I am writing this because you haven't done it for any of your questions yet). For more on this, see [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3399/111742)

Comment: Does that mean I should click on the up arrow? I take it the number 5 (now) implies that 5 people have done this. I just did and got the answer. Thanks.